pgfplots "no ... in font nullfont" with `y filter`
I get no ... in font nullfont warnings in the log when I use y filter in a plot (using the approach in this answer).
MWE:
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot[y filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1/10}\pgfmathresult}] coordinates {
        (1, 1)
        (2, 2)
        (3, 6)
    };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}

In the log:
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no Y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
etc.

The warning goes away if I remove the y filter option. I suspect it has something to do with the multiplication issue described here but if so, I don't know how to fix it.

The .log file contains (among other things) There is no ... in font nullfont! with successively 1.0e-1, 2.0e-1 and 6.0e-1. These originate from the usage of \pgfmathresult after the computation #1/10 with #1 being the y coordinates 1, 2 and 6. The warnings disappear if \pgfmathresult is removed.

Perfect. I don't know why I had \pgfmathresult in there -- it was not in the answer I was using as a reference. Thanks for the fix.
